# Template Flutter Project

Tags: android-studio, templates, flutter

I am using AndroidStudio whenever I create projects, I always have to add dependencies, create BaseClass,etc... Very boring process. So, how can I make a template Flutter Project in AndroidStudio

Comment: You just read through the docs or use duckduckgo

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template for Dart files doing the following:

File -> New -> Edit File Templates... -> Dart File

Though I think that's not exactly what you want, the easiest way I know would be having a base project and just replacing the files with a copy of that when you create a new project.

**EDIT: Just found this article, maybe it can be helpful: https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-changing-the-default-app-template-f3448386139f**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a flutter app template then, you can run **flutter create** command in

`'./{your-flutter-install}/packages/flutter-tools/templates/app/'` location.

Or if you want a full-fledged template with numerous modern and intuitive UI screens and functionalities, you can check out lots of [flutter templates](https://www.instamobile.io/flutter-app-templates/) out there in the market.