# Customize initial project template for Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to customize the starter template for a Flutter app. For projects that I work on I follow a very specific structure with my Themes, Blocs, Listeners, etc. I would love it if I could customize the starter template for Flutter so that I have everything all laid out and ready to use on doing something like `flutter create .`

I am aware of where the template is located. I was able to go to `[flutter_dir]/packages/flutter_tools/templates/app/lib/main.dart.tmpl` and customize the template.

But I am not able to figure out how I can add a new file/directory there. Let's say if I create a new file called `config.dart.tmpl` in the same directory as above, it does not get generated when I do `flutter create`

Any ideas how to get this to work or where I should be looking?

**NOTE**

1. I have already tried out other options like [Mason](https://pub.dev/packages/mason). It works fine for me, but I am more interested in doing it with default flutter tooling.
2. Already seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974852/6891637 and IDE file templates is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there's no easy way to create a template similar to skeleton, package, and plugin. There's an open [issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/89833) for this feature. However, if you really need to create one. You can explore how `skeleton` was added as a template on this [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/83530).

Or as a workaround, you can just create a Flutter project template on your repo and fork it when starting a project.

Comment: > you can just create a Flutter project template on your repo and fork it 
This is what I have done right now. Less than ideal; but has to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current issue about this topic : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77104

As Felix Angelov said, Mason and VeryGoodCLI are the best alternatives right now.